# “ 404 Not Found [IP: ] ” when try to install any ros kinetic package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install the rtabmap_ros package in the ros kinetic. but I have got the "404 not found [IP:]" error. so I tried to install any other ros packages and I found that I can't install any ros package and get the same error. also when I run "apt-get update" actually the ros repositories do not update.

I usually use a VPN, so I tried it with the VPN off, but it did not solve it. also, running below command from ros kinetic installation guide but it also did not work for me.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` file i have two files for ros. `ros-latest.list` and `ros.latest.list.save`. these files contain same context as below:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

i searched through my "source.list" file to find anything about ros but there was nothing relevant to ros in there.

my full error in installation of rtabmap_ros is like below:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-voxel-grid amd64 1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-125244-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-costmap-2d amd64 1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-182724-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-find-object-2d amd64 0.6.2-0xenial-20190320-160247-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-libg2o amd64 2016.4.24-0xenial-20180809-140114-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-move-base-msgs amd64 1.13.0-0xenial-20181107-005019-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rtabmap amd64 0.17.6-0xenial-20190320-143616-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros amd64 0.17.6-0xenial-20190320-184534-0800

  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-voxel-grid/ros-kinetic-voxel-grid_1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-125244-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-costmap-2d/ros-kinetic-costmap-2d_1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-182724-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-find-object-2d/ros-kinetic-find-object-2d_0.6.2-0xenial-20190320-160247-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-libg2o/ros-kinetic-libg2o_2016.4.24-0xenial-20180809-140114-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-move-base-msgs/ros-kinetic-move-base-msgs_1.13.0-0xenial-20181107-005019-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rtabmap/ros-kinetic-rtabmap_0.17.6-0xenial-20190320-143616-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros/ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros_0.17.6-0xenial-20190320-184534-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`
```

thanks for any help....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336084/%E2%80%9C-404-not-found-%5Bip:-%5D-%E2%80%9D-when-try-to-install-any-ros-kinetic-package/) by [Amir Reza Sadeghi](https://answers.ros.org/users/45248/amir-reza-sadeghi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-10-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-24**:
Do you perhaps have a proxy configured on your system?

Can you install any package with `apt`? Not just ROS packages, but any Ubuntu package?

**Comment by [Amir Reza Sadeghi](https://answers.ros.org/users/45248/amir-reza-sadeghi/) on 2019-10-24**:
today i installed two or three package with apt. but i get the error just for ros package installation. i will update the question to give complete error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you run `sudo apt update` recently?

`apt` is trying to download packages from March (`20190320`) for some reason.

If that doens't solve this, could you check #q325039?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amir Reza Sadeghi](https://answers.ros.org/users/45248/amir-reza-sadeghi/) on 2019-10-24**:
that worked. thank you for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-24**:
What helped exactly? `sudo apt update`? Or #q325039?

**Comment by [Amir Reza Sadeghi](https://answers.ros.org/users/45248/amir-reza-sadeghi/) on 2019-10-24**:
The #q325039 helped me.

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2021-04-18**:
`sudo apt update` fixed it